# What was Johan trying to achieve by setting fire in the book donation ceremony in Munich?

Tags: monster

I have completed watching the Monster anime. One thing is not cleared to me:

Johan eliminated all Schuwald's close friends just to get close to him. Once he became the secretary, his plan was to kill Schuwald. However, he changed his plan and set fire in that ceremony. My question is why Johan was so concerned with Schuwald. Why he even changed his plans on killing him?

If we look at the connections between them, we know that Johan's mother and Margot Langer were friends. Schuwald was aware of it. He even approached Johan's mother to search Margot. There he saw the twins. And that's it probably.

So, does Johan wanted to kill Schuwald initially because he saw Johan as a kid? In the end, he destroyed the books as it would be more painful for Schuwald?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest answer to your question is that Johan "awakened" in the midst of his scheme. After reading that book from his childhood, his character essentially reverted back to being one who simply wanted to be alone.

In other words, it became a cop out that transformed into a plot point for the final arc of the story.